# jQuery SVG vs. Raphael

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

I'm working on an interactive interface using SVG and JavaScript/jQuery, and I'm trying to decide between [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) and [jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html). I'd like to know

1. What the trade-offs are between the two
2. Where the development momentum seems to be.

I don't need the VML/IE support in Raphael, or the plotting abilities of jQuery SVG. I'm primarily interested in the most elegant way to create, animate, and manipulate individual items on an SVG canvas.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

I've recently used both Raphael and jQuery SVG - and here are my thoughts:

### Raphael

**Pros:** a good starter library, easy to do a LOT of things with SVG quickly. Well written and documented. Lots of examples and Demos. Very extensible architecture. Great with animation.

**Cons:** is a layer over the actual SVG markup, makes it difficult to do more complex things with SVG - such as grouping (it supports Sets, but not groups). Doesn't do great w/ editing of already existing elements.

### jQuery SVG

**Pros:** a jquery plugin, if you're already using jQuery. Well written and documented. Lots of examples and demos. Supports most SVG elements, allows native access to elements easily

**Cons:** architecture not as extensible as Raphael. Some things could be better documented (like configure of SVG element). Doesn't do great w/ editing of already existing elements. Relies on SVG semantics for animation - which is not that great.

### [SnapSVG](http://snapsvg.io/) as a pure SVG version of Raphael

SnapSVG is the successor of Raphael. It is supported only in the SVG enabled browsers and supports almost all the features of SVG.

### Conclusion

If you're doing something quick and easy, Raphael is an easy choice. If you're going to do something more complex, I chose to use jQuery SVG because I can manipulate the actual markup significantly easier than with Raphael. And if you want a non-jQuery solution then SnapSVG is a good option.

Comment: The documentation of RaphaelJS isn't that great either, it's limited and you sometimes have to go into SVG or jQuery documentation to get all information. That said, with the demo's (source code) available as well as the forum and many users, I manage to get the answers I need.

Comment: I've just started using Raphael and found the documentation to be some of the best I've come across for a javascript API, with very clear examples next to the more formal specifications

Comment: Don't forget that RaphaelJS has backwards compatibility to VML for Internet Explorer.  That's HUGE because SVG doesn't work on the older browsers.

Comment: Question was specifically about SVG, not backwards compatibility. If desire is cross-browser vector graphics, you're correct.

Comment: jQuery SVG has another con. You need the large jQuery library for it to work. I can't edit for some reason.

Comment: Another jQuery SVG con is that the project although the project is opensoucer (GPL and MIT) it seems to be abandoned by its developer (version 1.4.5 last update 28 april 2012). jquery.svg.dom causes some of conflicts with jQuery 1.8. Ideally I would wait for someone to take over the project and hopefully put it into github

Comment: @Hoffmann certainly now this answer isn't so great - with RaphaelJS getting major releases and big support from commercial entities, that project is probably a better option - however, other options, like Kinetic and fabric.js have come about to address the divide between SVG and Canvas for different types of graphics needs.

Comment: Raphael can't and won't manipulate existing SVG elements on your HTML document. This is a very serious limitation in my opinion.

Comment: @Dyin If you really need this, I would use SnapSVG: "Another unique feature of Snap is its ability to work with existing SVG." SnapSVG is the successor of Raphael and written by the same author. http://snapsvg.io/about/

Comment: is there any Ebook or course about `snapSVG`plugin? i just see some article...

Answer (score 53):

For posterity, I'd like to note that I ended up choosing Raphael, because of the clean API and "free" IE support, and also because the [active development](http://groups.google.com/group/raphaeljs) looks promising (event support was just added in 0.7, for instance). However, I'll leave the question unanswered, and I'd still be interested to hear about others' experiences using Javascript + SVG libraries.

Comment: The nice IE support for Raphael is great. Squares with rounded corners in IE?... no problem ;)

Answer (score 26):

I'm a huge fan of Raphael and the development momentum seems to be going strong (version 0.85 was released late last week). Another big plus is that its developer, [Dmitry Baranovskiy](http://dmitry.baranovskiy.com/), is currently working on a Raphael charting plugin, [g.raphael](http://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/g.raphael/tree/master), which looks like its shaping up to be pretty slick (there are a few samples of the output from the early versions on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/dmitry-baranovskiy/sets/72157620525949908/)).

However, just to throw another possible contender into the SVG library mix, Google's [SVG Web](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/) looks very promising indeed (even though I'm not a big fan of Flash, which it uses to render in non-SVG compliant browsers). Probably one to watch, especially with the upcoming [SVG Open conference](http://www.svgopen.org/2009/).

Comment: It's Raphael v. 1.5.2 at the moment.

Comment: it's not a big deal to notice that current version is 2.1.2. This comment is waiting to get correction by some another guy in a few years...

Comment: Kopat' Sho Ya Nashel, A few years later... It's Raphael v2.2.1 now

Answer (score 12):

Raphael is definitely easier to set up and get going, but note that there are ways of expressing things in SVG that are not possible in Raphael.  As noted above there are no "groups". This implies that you can't implement layers of Coordinate Transfomations. Instead there is only one coordinate transform available.

If your design depends on nested coordinate transforms, Raphael is not for you.

Answer (score 11):

Oh Raphael has moved on significantly since June.
There is a new charting library that can work with it and these are very eye catching.
Raphael also supports full SVG path syntax and is incorporating really advanced path methods. Come see 1.2.8+ at my site (Shameless plug) and then bounce over to the Dmitry's site from there.
http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/raphaelsource.html

Answer (score 6):

I think it is not totally unrelated but did you consider canvas? something like [Process JS](http://ejohn.org/blog/processingjs/) can make it simpler.

Comment: I have looked at both canvas in general and Processing in particular. The problem is that (as far I know) mouse events cannot be easily attached to individual items on the canvas, for features like drag and drop, unlike SVG, which is fully exposed to the DOM.

Comment: I haven't done extensive work with canvas but have a look at Flot - jquery plugin that uses canvas for charts. It handles mouseclicks pretty well.

Comment: Mouseclicks yes, but not dom events on items in the canvas. In fact, for Canvas you can't put the event handler on the canvas (because of IE), although you can put it on a div that holds the canvas.

Comment: canvas is great for bitmaps, SVG is great for vector graphics. The capability of SVG to scale is fantastic for that. I think canvas and SVG are complementary technologies.

Comment: Regarding mouse events for canvas, have a look at Easel.js which handles all this for you.

Answer (score 6):

You should also take a look at svgweb. It uses flash to render svg in IE, and optionally on other browsers (in the cases where it supports more than the browser itself does).

http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/

Answer (score 5):

I will throw my vote behind Raphael - the cross-browser support, clean API and consistent updates (so far) make it a joy to use.  It plays very nicely with jQuery too.  Processing is cool, but more useful as a demo for bleeding-edge stuff at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

As a Javascript beginner, I found Rapahel samples not so easy, I recommend  http://cancerbero.mbarreneche.com/raphaeltut, which is a real Step by step tutorial.

Answer (score 5):

For those who don't care about IE6/IE7, the same guy who wrote Raphael built an svg engine specifically for modern browsers: **Snap.svg** .. they have a really nice site with good docs: http://snapsvg.io

snap.svg couldn't be easier to use right out of the box and can manipulate/update existing SVGs or generate new ones. You can read this stuff on the snap.io about page but here's a quick run down:

**Cons**

- To make use of snap's features you must forgo on support for older browsers. Raphael supports browsers like IE6/IE7, snap features are only supported by IE9 and up, Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.

**Pros**

- Implements the full features of SVG like masking, clipping, patterns, full gradients, groups, and more.
- Ability to work with existing SVGs: content does not have to be generated with Snap for it to work with Snap, allowing you to create the content with any common design tools.
- Full animation support using a straightforward, easy-to-implement JavaScript API
- Works with strings of SVGs (for example, SVG files loaded via Ajax) without having to actually render them first, similar to a resource container or sprite sheet.

check it out if you're interested: http://snapsvg.io

Answer (score 3):

Since it's not mentioned here yet:
You should also take a look at [Dojox.drawing](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/drawing.html#dojox-drawing), which also provides good SVG drawing capabilities. It has a pretty impressive set of features. I'm just starting a project with it, but it seems to me that it's far superior (at least in terms of features) to Raphael and JQuerySVG.

This presentation convinced me to use it instead of Raphael/JQuerySVG:
http://www.slideshare.net/elazutkin/dojo-gfx-svg-in-the-real-world-2114082

Reference:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/index.html

Reference on Dojocampus:
http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/drawing

Download Dojo (including Dojox):
http://dojotoolkit.org/download/

Answer (score 3):

Another svg javascript library you might want to look at is d3.js. http://d3js.org/

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using RaphaelJS because it has great cross-browser abilities. However, some SVG &  VML effects can't be achieved with RaphaelJS (complex gradients...).

Google has also developped a library of its own to enable SVG support in IE:
http://svgweb.googlecode.com/files/svgweb-2009-08-20-B.zip

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need VML and IE8 support then use Canvas (PaperJS for example). Look at latest IE10 demos for Windows 7. They have amazing animations in Canvas. SVG is not capable to do anything close to them. 
Overall Canvas is available at all mobile browsers. SVG is not working at early versions of Android 2.0- 2.3 (as I know)

Yes, Canvas is not scalable, but it so fast that you can redraw the whole canvas faster then browser capable to scroll view port.

From my perspective Microsoft's optimizations provides means to use Canvas as regular GDI engine and implement graphics applications like we do them for Windows now.

Comment: For pure graphics rendering, I absolutely agree. The one thing that SVG/VML offer which canvas does not is a DOM and an event hierarchy, since drawn elements are full DOM objects rather than a raw bitmap. With canvas, X/Y click coords are the best than can be done. At any rate, the project is long since over, so it's not currently relevant, but thanks for your answer. :)