# Best web technology for building dynamic charts

Tags: graphics, graph, svg, charts

I need to build a custom designed bar chart that displays some simple data.  Below are my requirements.  Can anyone suggest the best web technology for my requirements.

- high browser compatibility
- ability to draw shapes
- ability to fill shapes with gradients
- ability to have onclick and onmouseover events for the different shapes (bars in the chart).

Thanks guys. I was thinking of using svg but looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) - it's **SVG/VML**.
It says:

**Browser compatibility:**

> Raphaël currently supports Firefox
>   3.0+, Safari 3.0+, Opera 9.5+ and Internet Explorer 6.0+.

**Ability to draw shapes**

circle, rect, ellipse, image, text, path

**Ability to fill shapes with gradients**

yes

**Ability to have onclick and onmouseover events**

yes:

> ... every graphical object you
>   create is also a DOM object, so you
>   can attach JavaScript event handlers
>   or modify them later.

Everything in the [reference](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html)

On top of that, there's a plugin called [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) which makes the creation of charts easier.

Answer (score 2):

Simple data - [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image_charts.html) or [Google Visualization API](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/interactive_charts.html) may suit you.

Details for all features of image charts can be found on the [Chart feature list](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/chart_params.html)

You may also take a look at the [comparison](http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/docs/choosing.html) of the Charts API and the Visualization API.

Answer (score 0):

Another candidate of course is [JQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html) - if you're already familiar with jquery you may prefer this one.

There's a comparison of JQuery SVG and Raphaël on SO:
[jQuery SVG vs. Raphael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588718/jquery-svg-vs-raphael)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Adobe Flex.  Below is an example of how easy pie chart creation can be in Flex:

```
   <mx:Panel title="Pie Chart">
 <mx:PieChart id="myChart" 
    dataProvider="{expenses}" 
    showDataTips="true"
 >
    <mx:series>
       <mx:PieSeries 
            field="Amount" 
            nameField="Expense" 
            labelPosition="callout"
       />
    </mx:series>
 </mx:PieChart>
 <mx:Legend dataProvider="{myChart}"/>
```

Based on your criteria:

- high browser compatibility: Flex is used on more than 95% of all browsers and behaves the same in all browsers.  No more need to check if your web app is running in ie, firefox, chrome, etc... because any browser that has a flash player is compatible.
- ability to draw shapes: Flash's greatest strength is the ability to draw.  Charts are completely customizable and skinnable to achieve the look you need.
- Ability to fill shapes with gradients - done easily by setting style attributes or a custom skin.
- ability to have onclick and onmouseover events for the different shapes - see [this link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf65c3d-7fff.html) for some easy ways to create user interactions with charts.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i hope this link may help you i found it while searching for a solution similar to what you're looking for:

http://www.artetics.com/Articles/using-various-javascript-libraries-to-create-pie-chart

i'm trying gRaphael, i'm having difficulties on finding documentation though. you have to read the code and use the exploded instead of the min.js

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share jquery.jqplot.js. It has lots of jQuery options, but depends on other plugins such as syntaxhighliter etc.