# Is there an easy way to clear an SVG element's contents?

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, svg

In HTML, I can clear a `<div>` element with this command:

```
div.innerHTML = "";
```

Is there an equivalent if I have an `<svg>` element?  I can't find an `innerHTML` nor `innerXML` or even `innerSVG` method.

I know the SVG DOM is a superset of the XML DOM, so I know I can do something like this:

```
while (svg.lastChild) {
    svg.removeChild(svg.lastChild);
}
```

But this is both tedious and slow. Is there a faster or easier way to clear an SVG element?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You already gave one answer: you can always just loop over all children and remove them. If you think that you have too many child nodes then maybe you want to replace the svg node by an empty one. If your svg node has some attributes you may use a  tag where you place all the child nodes and then just replace the  node with an empty one.

Answer (score 45):

If you're using jQuery, you can just do

```
$("#svgid").empty();
```

This [deletes all child elements](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) of the svg while leaving its other attributes like width and height intact.

Comment: Removes <defs> tags  :(

Comment: To expand on john ktejik's commnet. Using empty() clears all the definitions. Using the loop only clears out those definitions specifically associated with a removed child element.

Answer (score 31):

Use d3.js. This will remove all contents nodes from svg.

```
svg.selectAll("*").remove();
```

Comment: Had to use this over `svg.html(null)` for it to work with IE 11.  Thank you.

Comment: Note that `svg` variable here is a d3 selection, not an SVGSVGElement object as in the question. It might be fixed with `d3.select(svg).selectAll("*").remove();`

Answer (score 11):

I agree to use the clone and replace the element with the cloned one.

Only one line code:

```
svg.parentNode.replaceChild(svg.cloneNode(false), svg);
```

Comment: what if you have existing defs in it?

Comment: put your defs out of this element.

Answer (score 4):

I've tried `svg.text("")` and it seems to work. Clears out all the inner text, keeps the attributes.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep defs of your svg as me use this

```js
function clear(prnt){
    let children = prnt.children;
    for (let i=0;i<children.length;){
        let el = children[i];
        if (el.tagName!=='defs'){
            el.remove();
        }else(i++);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to loop, just assign an empty string

```
svg.innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the clone and replace the element with the cloned one.

```
    var parentElement = svg.parentElement
    var emptySvg = svg.cloneNode(false);
    parentElement.removeChild(svg);
    parentElement.appendChild(emptySvg);
```

This will append the svg at the end,
you might want to get the element before and append accordinaly

Answer (score 0):

use this? http://keith-wood.name/svg.html

there's also raphael: [jQuery SVG vs. Raphael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588718/jquery-svg-vs-raphael)

I'd be tempted to trawl through and see who they're doing their `.destroy()` methods.

Comment: Looks like they're doing exactly what Aseem is: paperproto.clear = function () {
            var c = this.canvas;
            while (c.firstChild) {
                c.removeChild(c.firstChild);
            }

Answer (score 0):

```
element = document.getElementById("elementID");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

I got the idea from http://www.carto.net/svg/manipulating_svg_with_dom_ecmascript/

Comment: That would remove the element itself rather than just empty it but does indeed work for SVG.

Comment: how does removing the entire element 'work'?  This is not what was asked.