# HTML5 Canvas and scaling

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

After I draw a line on `canvas` I scale document (with CTRL+Wheel), as it turned out, a line is raster and it looks pretty ugly after scaling. How can I solve the issue? Is there something better then redrawing each time when document is scaled?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can only use the canvas element, there is no other way to display a sharp line, than redrawing it when zooming. This is because the canvas doesn't support vector graphics.

[Svg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) could be a option, if you're able to use a different technology.

Comment: +1 for SVG. It's a really underappreciated technology. Most people don't realize that SVGs can be procedurally generated and manipulated through javascript just like you can work with a canvas, and it is even more widely available.

Comment: You've got some options [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588718/jquery-svg-vs-raphael)

Comment: @Cerbus,Thank you for your answer!